# How to fetch file size and path from My file manager ?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to fetch the path,size and name from an file manager in Nexus 7.

For that I am trying to execute the below code to fetch the content I always get the cursor null

```
String[] projection = { MediaColumns.SIZE };
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

I tried this also but the same problem in getting the content resolver

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri).available()
```

And i always get `failed to find provider info for org.openintents.cmfilemanager` when trying to get the content resolver.

I might be missing something very simple.

Comment: content://org.openintents.cmfilemanager/storage/emulated/0/Download/44476898.jpg.

Comment: That's not the right URI. There are methods to give you the SD card URI.

Comment: thanks katzoft for the response. If i do uri.getPath() i get /mnt/sdcard/Download/44476898.jpg...is it not the correct uri ?.On this uri if i open the input stream it fails.

Comment: Are you trying to get the jpg file size or the file manager size? I don't understand your question.

Comment: i am trying to fetch the jpg file zie

Comment: So you can just pass the Uri to the file...

Comment: You mean to create a File with instance with that uri (with uri.getPath ?) and then get the length ?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Make sure you have requested the relevant permission to access the external storage though.

Comment: thanks a ton katzoft it worked...so is it not good to use Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null) for image file retrievals with projection being "MediaColumns.SIZE"  ? because this fails in when opening files from sdcard.